# SQL find duplicate entry and insert into new column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000, sql-update

I have a table with columns: Date, Phone, Name, and Event.

I need a query that will first recognize the duplicate phone entry, and then assign the name of whichever one has the earlier date to the event column.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  Also, you want to place the `Name` from the original record into the `Event` of the duplicate record(s)?  Also also, what do you consider duplicate phone numbers?  Is 555-555-5555 the same as (555) 555-5555?

Comment: if the phone column is a duplicate, i want it to take the record with the earliest date and put it's name into the event column of the duplicate with the older date...hopefully that makes sense. duplicate as in 1234567 being the same as 1234567

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
UPDATE x
   SET x.event = y.name
  FROM YOUR_TABLE x
  JOIN YOUR_TABLE y ON y.phone = x.phone
  JOIN (SELECT t.phone,
               MIN(t.date) As min_date
          FROM YOUR_TABLE t
      GROUP BY t.phone
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) z ON z.phone = y.phone
                              AND z.min_date = y.date
                              AND z.min_date < x.date
```

But it doesn't address if there are duplicates of the minimum value.

Comment: That updates the record earlier date, I think @sqlman wants the record with the older dates updated.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - I was kind of confused by your question, but then I realized it looks like he responded after I edited his question, but I assure you, the comment was there first :)  Your query updates the records with the later dates, but I thought he wanted the `Name` from the earliest record into the `Event` of the later records, while your query just makes the Event and Name of the record the same.  I could be totally wrong on what @sqlman wants though, my brain doesn't seem to be working right tonight.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTales "but I thought he wanted the Name from the earliest record into the Event of the later records" --this is correct

Comment: @OMG Ponies -- so close!  Assuming a table name of `Events`, Query Analyzer gave me a `The table 'Events' is ambiguous.` error (this was in 2005 though), so I changed the update statement to `UPDATE x...` and that seemed to work just fine.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - Huzzah!  Works on my test table.  The *only* caveat I would add is @sqlman may want to modify the `z.phone = y.phone` portion of the query to strip out `(`, `)` and `-` characters in the phone number if they just want to compare the actual digits if that's an issue, but the core of it works.